# sharepoint programming in C#

Tags: c#, windows, sharepoint, web-applications, web-parts

I want to learn about programming SharePoint - SP - in c#, i have VS 2010 professional. but creating a visual webpart requires, SP to be installed on the same machine.
my question is, is there any free (express version of SP, for leaning purpose) if not, can i use a remote SP server to develop web parts in C#, is there a trick to use a remote SP server with my VS 2010 Pro, from an XP machine SP3, that is my system config. Your help is appreciated guys.

Have a great programming Day, here at STACK!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also say that your OS must be 64 bit. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx) is very helpful article how to install SP on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

[Microsoft SharePoint Foundation](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5970) is free and should be enough to get you started. However, I am pretty sure you can't run it on Windows XP - you'll need Windows 7 or even better Windows 2008 Server.

Comment: Thanks ! will try that, i also have found some interesting documents about SP, here are the links if anybody's interested

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7204